# Button onclick event is not calling javascript function in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm calling a javascript function in php. it works when i call alert() method directly on click. here is my code

```
echo "<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' >
          <div class='fileupload fileupload-new' style='width: 250px;' data-provides='fileupload'><input type='hidden' value='' name=''>
          <div class='fileupload-preview thumbnail' style='width: 390px; height: 250px; '></div>
          <div>
         <span class='btn btn-file btn-success'><span class='fileupload-new'>Select image</span>
         <span class='fileupload-exists'>Change</span><input type='file' name=''></span>
      <button name='changepic' value='Save' class='btn btn-danger fileupload-exists' id='changeSitepic' onclick=\"alert('hi');\">Save</button>
       </div>
       </div>
       </form>";
```

this is the line which causing problem. it works for direct alert() method

```
<button name='changepic' value='Save' class='btn btn-danger fileupload-exists' id='changeSitepic' onclick=\"alert('hi');\">Save</button>
```

but when i call it through other javascript function, then this won't work.

```
<button name='changepic' value='Save' class='btn btn-danger fileupload-exists' id='changeSitepic' onclick=\"changeSitepic();\">Save</button>
```

here is the javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeSitepic(){

     alert('hi');

        }

</script>
```

I unable to find where i'm doing wrong. please help.

Comment: Post your PHP code instead of HTML.

Comment: @KarolGasienica done

Comment: What if you inspect your code with f.ex. `F12` in a browser? How does it look there in source? Maybe are there any errors in log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your attribute 'id' and function name are same. Please change the 'ID' and try. Change your button like this and try. It may help you

```
 <button name='changepic' value='Save' class='btn btn-danger fileupload-exists' id='changeSitepic_id' onclick="return changeSitepic()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

also there is no need to use double quotes and escape them. just use single quotes.

```
onclick='javascript:changeSitepic()'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your onclick

```
onclick=\"javascript:alert('hi');\"
```

Comment: He already tried that, and I think in `alert()` will be some function he wants to run `onclick`.

Comment: It is not calling  `changeSitepic`